# Convert nvarchar to datetime in SQL Server 2008 arithmetic overflow

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am trying to convert `nvarchar` values with the format `3/7/2013` to `datetime` but I can't quite figure it out. I am using SQL Server 2008 and keep getting an

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

error.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine:

```
SELECT CAST (N'3/7/2013' as datetime)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you thank you thank you. Do you know how I can convert an entire column that way?

Comment: SELECT CAST (*column* as datetime) FROM Table

Comment: Note that the result of the cast can be either July 3rd or March 7th depending on server or user settings. It is better to always specify which one you want. i.e. CONVERT(datetime, column, 101) if you want March 7th and CONVERT(datetime, column, 103) if you want July 3rd,