# Get data after year 2012 SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get data after year 2012.

Date is saved in `nvarchar` format in a table. For example: `12/31/2010`

Column also has some other values like 'Confidential', I don't want this row.

I am trying a query (shown below) but it is not succeed :-

```
select * 
from tbl_ProductionWells 
where CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), wellstatusdate, 103) > CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), '01/01/2012', 103)
```

Edited :-

I tried this :-

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_ProductionWells 
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, CAST(wellstatusdate AS date)) > 2012
```

But it is giving an error (shown below), This column also has some text values like 'not available','Confidential' .. :-

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

**Note:- I can't change column datatype as it also contains some other texts.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you storing dates as nvarchar  text?

Comment: Is 'Confidential' the only non-Date value in this field?  If not, are the stored dates always in the MM/DD/YYYY format in your example?

Comment: Yes, all data in MM/DD/YYYY format, but column has some text too..

Comment: To add to what @MitchWheat said, you should normalize your data. Storing multiple pieces of data in a single column is a violation of 1NF. Normalize your data and use proper datatypes. If you get the ddl right, the dml is really simple.

Comment: Fix this flawed design - a date should be stored in a `DATE` or `DATETIME2` column, and if you need to have a `Confidential` information, make that a separate flag (e.g. a `IsConfidential BIT` column) or something. Don't use this crappy design and work around the flaws of it - **FIX** the design!

Comment: I hope this link can help you, "SQL Convert Nvarchar(255) to DateTime problem" ---> http://stackoverflow.com/q/2783505/771579  and "Convert nvarchar to datetime in SQL Server 2008 arithmetic overflow" -----> http://stackoverflow.com/q/19883692/771579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: **Store date values in `DATE` columns, datetimes in `DATETIME2` columns. Always choose proper data type for your data**

You have to convert your `NVARCHAR` to `DATE`, then compare it to `2012-01-01`
OR you can extract the 'year' part of your string.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl_ProductionWells
WHERE   CONVERT(DATE, wellstatusdate) >= '2012-01-01'
```

The best choice is to change your column's data type to `DATE`. After that, you can do lots of magicial things with those values. Store the 'Confidental' flag in another column.

**EDIT**
Some additional info:

Please note, that the STRING -> DATE conversion depends on the current session's language.

Run this batch to see the difference:

```
DECLARE @DateAsChar VARCHAR(32) = '01/02/12';
SET LANGUAGE us_english
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(DATE, @DateAsChar), 120)
SET LANGUAGE Hungarian
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(DATE, @DateAsChar), 120)
SET LANGUAGE Deutsch
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(DATE, @DateAsChar), 120)
```

Comment: Thanks Pred, but it fetches data but giving error as column also contains some values that are not in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format.

Comment: Please use the ISDATE function to filter the non-date values, or if you can, filter them by value with a NOT IN condition.

Comment: I've added some additional info. I hope it will help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     tbl_ProductionWells
               WHERE    ISDATE(wellstatusdate) = 1
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   DATEPART(YEAR, CAST(wellstatusdate AS DATE)) > 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all data from the table that is a date using [IsDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx), then work with that dataset only.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM tbl_ProductionWells WHERE ISDATE(wellstatusdate) = 1)
WHERE CAST(wellstatusdate as Date) > @YOURDATE
```